# Unexpected token when serving json file

Tags: node.js

I have a simple nodejs file:

```
const data = require('./gameData.js')

app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

And this is the contents of the gameData.js file:

```
{
  "systemText": 
    {
      "playGame": "Play game"
    }
}
```

This is all valid json.
But when I run the node file is says: `"unexpected token :"` on the `"systemText:"`
Why doesn't it like the colon symbol?

Comment: Make the extension .json or write the module.exports = { your object } beforehead

Comment: Thanks, I've now changed that but it now says "app is not defined".

Comment: You should define it. app is a variable made from calling an express main function. 
```const express = require("express");
const app = express();```

I'd reccomend you to read this article about node.js for a smoother start https://medium.com/@LindaVivah/the-beginners-guide-understanding-node-js-express-js-fundamentals-e15493462be1